# Django app is including encoding notations in strings when it saves database entries

Tags: django, encoding

I’m facing my first encoding-related bug and I’m stumped. The problem is in a Django app with a form which updates existing database entries. When the update form is used to make changes to an entry, I’m finding that the new entry data includes encoding-related notations like quotation marks, parentheses, and the u (encoding mark). It appears that I’ve made some sort of mistake which confuses Django about what encoding my strings are in.

**To summarize, this is the problem:**
Initial state: Entry title field is *FooBar*
Desired state: Entry title field is *FooBar2*
What I get instead: Entry title field is *(u’FooBar2’,)*
These encoding markers are getting printed out in my Django app, and I confirmed that they're also there when I access the database directly from the Python shell (as in the example which follows)

```
>>>entry.title
u"(u'FooBar2',)"
```

---

Any idea why my form and view are saving these notations into the database? How can I stop it?

---

**This is the form I’m using to edit the database entries:**

```
class EntryEditForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(label=u'Entry title.', max_length=100)
    target = forms.CharField(label=u'Entry target', required=False)
    username = forms.CharField(label=u'Entry-specific username', max_length=100, required=False)
    password = forms.CharField(label=u'Entry-specific password', max_length=100, required=False)
```

**This is the view which is used to edit the database entries:**

```
def editentry_page(request): 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EntryEditForm(request.POST)
        entryid = unquote(request.POST['entryid'])
        if form.is_valid():
            entry = request.user.entry_set.get(id=entryid)
            entry.title=form.cleaned_data['title'],
            entry.username=form.cleaned_data['username'],
            entry.password=form.cleaned_data['password'],
            entry.targetemail=form.cleaned_data['targetemail'],
            entry.user=User.objects.get(username=request.user)
            entry.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/%s/' % request.user.username)
    elif 'entryid' in request.GET: 
        entryid = unquote(request.GET['entryid'])
        try:
            selectedentry = request.user.entry_set.get(id=entryid) 
            title = selectedentry.title
            targetemail = selectedentry.targetemail
            username = selectedentry.username
            password = selectedentry.password
        except (Entry.DoesNotExist):
            raise Http404(u'This entry does not exist or is not your entry') 
        entry = Entry.objects.get(id=entryid)
        form = EntryEditForm({
            'title': entry.title, 
            'email': entry.email, 
            'target': entry.target, 
            'username': entry.username, 
            'password': entry.password, 
            })

    else: 
        raise Http404(u'No entry selected - return to your entries to try again.') 
    variables = RequestContext(request, {'form': form, ‘entryid': unquote(request.GET['entryid']),})
    return render_to_response('entry_edit.html', variables)
```

**This is the entry model**

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    target = models.CharField(unique=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

Comment: can you add your entry model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> entry.title=form.cleaned_data['title'],
> ```

The final comma is turning it into a tuple in your view. Stop doing that.